# Download file from URL to the file system with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova

How can I download a file from URL to the file system with PhoneGap? I see there is a plugin for this (http://www.toforge.com/2011/02/phonegap-android-plugin-for-download-files-from-url-on-sd-card/), but it's only for Android.

Are there any cross-platform solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the FileWriter is supported on most platforms. I haven't tried it, but it might work for you.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File